# 'git push' not creating remote branch on Github

Tags: git, github

I made some changes on my local branch (e.g., feature_01)

```
    $gid add .
    $git commit -m 'check in features'
    $git push origin feature_01`
```

All runs successfully.  I am also able to open the link and create a PR to merge the code change on Github.  However,  I am not able to see the feature_01 branch on Github.  Is it expected?  according to multiple sources, it should create a remote branch on Github though.

Any pointers on what's going wrong?
Thanks!

I submitted PR multiple times using the steps similar as above.  None of them created remote branch on Github.  Other than that, everything is working fine though